# Error when plotting with StatET in Eclipse

Tags: r, eclipse-plugin, statet

I have a weird error, which shows up when I try to plot simple functions in StatET via Eclipse. It says:  *Error in function (name="rj.gd", width=7, height=7, size.unit="in", :
[RJ-GD/R-Java] Cannot get Java method 'gdPPI'.*

I really have no clue whats going wrong, I reinstalled R and StatET twice but it doesn't help at all.

Eclipse Installation Details tells me that StatET has version 2.0.3b and the RJ libraries have version 1.0.3b if that helps.

Anyone has a solution or at least an idea? I appreciate your help!

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 0):

This was taken from statet page:

```
StatET 2.0 is available for Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. The new version uses RJ 1.0, which requires the installation/update of a new version of its R packages 'rj' and 'rj.gd'. For detail please check the installation instructions  http://www.walware.de/it/statet/installation.mframe
```

Did you install/update rj and rj.gd packages? What Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: HI Dzidas, I downloaded the packages as described on walware.de, so those should be correct.
When I click on Help->About Eclipse, it just says Version: Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149

Maybe I should add that that this problem occurs not on my system, I just have to fix it, everything works fine on my personal computer.

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse once plugin was installed?

Comment: Another thing I noticed: Is it possible that it's not working because the Eclipse Version making the trouble is "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers"?

Comment: yes, I did restart, I was prompted to restart at every installation

Comment: I don't think so - Eclipse is a platform, so it should run any plugin. As I understood from the error, Eclipse can't find appropriate method gdPPI, which should be provided by RJ-GD/R-Java.

Comment: Okay, thats sounds like an all-nighter reinstalling Eclipse + all the plugins + all the existing workbenches... what a joy :) but I hope this will solve the problem